# Time complexity for two pieces of code

Tags: java, time-complexity

We've got 2 pieces of code:

```
int a = 3; 
while (a <= n) {
    a = a * a;
}
```

And:

```
public void foo(int n, int m) { 
    int i = m; 
    while (i > 100) 
        i = i / 3; 
    for (int k = i ; k >= 0; k--) { 
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j*=2) 
            System.out.print(k + "\t" + j); 
        System.out.println(); 
    } 
}
```

What is the time complexity of them?
I think that the first one is: O(logn), because it's progressing to N with power of 2.
So maybe it's O(log<sup>2</sup>n) ?

And the second one I believe is: O(nlog2n), because it's progressing with jumps of 2, and also running on the outer loop.

Am I right?

Comment: The important thing is not looking at the data, but looking at the number of steps the algorithm needs.  If the input doubles, how does the number of steps scale?  Same?  Double? Other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, that first code will run in O(Log(LogN)) time. It's simple to understand in this way

1. Before first iteration you have 3 in power 1
2. After first iteration you have 3 in power 2
3. After second iteration you have 3 in power 4
4. After third iteration you have 3 in power 8
5. After fourth iteration you have 3 in power 16
   and so on.

In the second code first piece of code will work in O(LogM) time, because you divide i by 3 every time. The second piece of code C  times (C equals 100 in your case) will perform O(LogN) operations, because you multiply j by 2 every time, so it runs in O(CLogN), and you have complexity O(LogM + CLogN)

Comment: While your answer might be correct, without clarification it's useless, IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

For the first one, it is indeed O(log(log(n))). Thanks to @MarounMaroun for the hint, I could find this:

```
l(k) = l(k-1)^2
l(0) = 3
```

Solving this system yields:

```
l(k) = 3^(2^k)
```

So, we are looking for such a `k` that satisfies `l(k) = n`. So simply solve that:

[image]

This means we found:

[image]

The second code is seems misleading. It looks like O(n*log(n)), but the outer loop limited to 100. So, if `m < 100`, then it obviously is O(m*log(n)). Otherwise, it kind of depends on where exactly m is. Consider these two:

- m: `305 -> 101 -> 33`
- m: `300 -> 100`

In the first case, the outer loop would run 33 times. Whereas the second case would cause 100 iterations. I'm not sure, but I think you can write this as being O(log(n)).

Comment: I think the first loop is O(loglog(n))

Comment: I'll delete it from my answer and rethink in the meanwhile.

Comment: The first loop will loop until `a <= n`. So we're looking for `k` such that `2^2^k <= n`. When I see this, my instincts tell me "log of log".

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Yes that is what I thought as well, but I can't really find a good explanation for it, other than "my instincts" :)

Comment: Well.. direct solving of the equation will yield that result, "proving" my instincts :))

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I updated my answer using your technique. Thank you for teaching me a new insight.

Comment: Now that's an answer.. too bad I can't +1 more than once. I think this answer will be helpful to many users, should gain more views :)